WooCommerce: expiring date for products (and on sale some days before)
I am new to the portal. In WooCommerce I would need to associate with each product a date from which the product is on offer (possibly with the price lowered) and a second date from which the product is no longer available. I don't know if this is feasible with custom fields or if there is a module that allows this functionality.
Thanks
